# Is it possible to navigate to App.xaml from Mainpage.xaml page

Tags: windows-phone-7, app.xaml

Is it possible to navigate to the APP.xaml from mainpage.xaml? As far as I know it is called by default. It calls Application_Launching() when the application launches.

Can any one help me on this? I want to navigate to the App.xaml page so that it Directly calls the automatescript.cs file to launch tha application. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a very similar question, "Is it possible to navigate to the APp.xaml from mainpage.xaml", asked here :-

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/102491.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you describe what you are trying to achieve rather than be so specific. However, with your question phrased as it is, the answer is *no*.

The WP7 navigation framework revolves around the concept of pages. For your application to navigate to a 'xaml' file it must be a page (as opposed to a user control or something else). Your `app.xaml` file does not describe a page, hence it cannot be navigated to.